# coordinate 2 foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

i have 2 foreach loops, they both loop through the same array; however one loops through the array after str_replace is used, while the other does not use str_replace;

my problem; how do i coordinate these 2 loops so that they will loop through the same array at the same time?

sorry if my problem is not as descriptive;

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
$unalteredcontents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
foreach ($unalteredcontents as $fname2)
{
    if (($fname2 != '.') && ($fname2 != '..'))
    {
        $url = "http://mywebsite.com/folder/" . $userid . "/" . $fname2 . "";
        next($fname2);
    }
}
$contents = str_replace("-", '', $contents);
$contents = str_replace(".pdf", '', $contents);

foreach ($contents as $fname)
{
    if (($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..'))
    {
        $sql_select = "INSERT INTO `database`.`column` (`data`, `fileurl`) VALUES ('" . $fname . "', '" . $url . "') ";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time" ? As in multithreading ?

Comment: `str_replace()` returns a string, and you're using that in `foreach`?

Comment: You don't, you have one foreach loop that does both tasks

Comment: Do u mean you want to create url and insert into database at the same time?

Comment: You're not really -doing- anything and there's no reason that you couldn't accomplish what it appears you think you want to do in a single loop.  You should sit down and think about what you want to accomplish and try to express it more clearly - it would probably result in you solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$unalteredcontents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
$contents = str_replace("-", '', $unalteredcontents);
$contents = str_replace(".pdf", '', $contents);

foreach ($contents as $key => $fname)
{
    if (($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..'))
    {
        $url = "http://mywebsite.com/folder/" . $userid . "/" . $unalteredcontents[$key];
        $sql_select = "INSERT INTO `database`.`column` (`data`, `fileurl`) VALUES ('" . $fname . "', '" . $url . "') ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Elen's solution is more general, while mine takes advantage of the fact that you can take two parallel arrays with the same keys and just use the key from the `foreach` to index into the array you're not `foreach`ing over.

Comment: here i always try to keep original code untouched as much as possible, because i don't know whether it's used anywhere else on script =)

Comment: True, and it's sort of "bad" to use your current knowledge that the replacements won't touch whether `"."` or `".."` will appear in `$contents`. But it's probably ever so slightly faster. Shrug, it's a bit of a wash either way.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your question. but i give it a go:

```
$unalteredcontents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
foreach ($unalteredcontents as $fname2)
{
    if (($fname2 != '.') && ($fname2 != '..'))
    {
        $url = "http://mywebsite.com/folder/" . $userid . "/" . $fname2 . "";

        $contents = str_replace("-", '', $fname2);
        $contents = str_replace(".pdf", '', $contents);

        $sql_select = "INSERT INTO `database`.`column` (`data`, `fileurl`) VALUES ('" . $contents. "', '" . $url . "') ";
    }
}
```